# how to change nested if-else to when statements using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following block of code and want to reduce it using Kotlin. How can I do that?

```
if (name == nameArray[0]) {
    // The statement
} else if(name == nameArray[1]) {
    // The statement
} else if(name == nameArray[2]) {
    // The statement
} else if(name == nameArray[3]) {
    // The statement
} else {
    // The statement
}
```

Comment: Are you really checking the same index in the array 3 times or is that a typo?

Comment: What is nested here?

Comment: Alright, now fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Implement switch case in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138172/how-to-implement-switch-case-in-kotlin)

Comment: You could go the other way round and iterate the `nameArray`, because `name` stays the same, doesn't it? Could you provide a minimal example and the exact type of `nameArray`?

Comment: There are plenty of resources on internet about how when expression works in kotlin [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html), I dont see anything in this question that cant be answered by a simple google search.

Comment: You can simply use a `for` loop to check this.

Comment: @mightyWOZ it is not just about the when statement. there is a little more to it, which can be shortenend.

Comment: @sadankhan does one of the answers answer your question? :)

Answer (score 5):

**If the array is small and you want to map an action to each index:**

You could use [`indexOfFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) to determine the smallest index which meats your condition. Then you can use a `when` statement to decide what to do.

```
when(nameArray.indexOfFirst{ it == name }) {
    0 -> // do something
    1 -> // do something else
    //...
    else -> // do something different
}
```

---

In case you might want to do the same thing for multiple indices you can use comma separated values. In case the indices are consecutive, you can use ranges:

```
when(nameArray.indexOfFirst{ it == name }) {
    0 -> // do something
    1, 2 -> // do the same thing for 1 and 2
    in 3..6 -> // do the same thing for 3, 4, 5 and 6
    //...
    else -> // do something different
}
```

In order to use this syntax it is a good idea to do index retrieval (like shown) first.

**If the array is big and you really only want to check for specific elements:**

```
when(name) {
    nameArray[0] -> // do something
    nameArray[1] -> // do something
    nameArray[2] -> // do something
    nameArray[3] -> // do something
    else -> // other action
}
```

Comment: in the worst case (say array has million items, and matching item is last one) `nameArray.indexOfFirst{ it == name }` ***will cost you lot more than 3, 4 simple comparisons as in the question***

Comment: @mightyWOZ true, but then it wouldn't be feasible to list an action for each of those cases (using `when` what you seemed to have suggested) either. the answer was tailored to the question and its use-case. it was meant to be short and concise.

Comment: First, question doesn't say anything about the size of array. ***(can be 5 or 5000000)*** second, ***question only deals with five cases irrespective of the size of the array, which can be handled very easily by when***

Comment: @mightyWOZ ok, I see your point. I was thinking that OP wants to cover all cases of the array (because it starts with zero and has consecutive indices) (which then would mean that it can't be that big). still if the array is not large, I would most likely go with what I suggested, especially because of the second part of the answer. anyway thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `when` to simplify it as below

```
when(name) {
    nameArray[0] -> //statement
    nameArray[1] -> //statement
    nameArray[2] -> //statement
    nameArray[3] -> //statement
    else -> //statement
}
```

Alternatively, if you can use an enum instead of the `nameArray` as below

```
enum class Names {
    NAME_1, NAME_2, NAME_3
}
```

And have `name` of the `Names` enum type, you can then use the `when` clause as below, which is a cleaner way and is more readable

```
when(name) {
    Names.NAME_1 -> //statement
    Names.NAME_2 -> //statement
    Names.NAME_3 -> //statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a better and more powerful Kotlin construct, `when`.

It works similarly to switch-case constructs but you can use expression too, check [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) for more.

Specific to your example you may write:

```
when (name) {
    nameArray[0] -> {
    //The statement
    }
    nameArray[1] -> {
    //The statement
    }
    nameArray[2] -> {
    //The statement
    }
    nameArray[3] -> {
    //The statement
    }
    else -> { 
    //Executes when conditions are not met
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you want to do, but in my opinion a when statement is over-complicating this. In your original code you just want to determine if the array contains the `name` value in any of the indices from 0 to 3 and respond accordingly.

```
if ((nameArray.indexOfFirst(name::equals) in 0..3) { 
    // The statement
} else {
    // The else branch
}
```

Comment: it's not completely clear from the question, but he might want to do different things for different indices.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way: Iterate the array instead of `if`-`else` every possible index of the array:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val nameArray: Array<String> = arrayOf("naam", "nombre", "name", "Name")
    val name: String = "name";

    for (i in 0..(nameArray.size - 1)) {
        if (name == nameArray[i]) {
            println("The statement should be executed on index " + i)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The statement should be executed on index 2
```

Comment: you could use `i in 0 until nameArray` instead `0..(nameArray.size - 1)`, it's not shorter but maybe easier to read :)

Comment: @WilliMentzel What about `nameArray.indices` ?

Comment: @xinaiz or even better `forEachIndexed` :)

Comment: @WilliMentzel One could use an `iterator.withIndex()`, too... There are plenty of possibilities in Kotlin ;-) Most of them more readable than my example, I admit...