# is there a way to pass value of String as a java command

Tags: android, string

I have 10 EditTexts defined as L1, L2 etc. All of them are initially hidden. Based on a integer value - say 4, I would like to unhide only L1 to L4. Is there any method for doing so?

Something like this:

```
public void displaydynamicdata(int count){
    int i= 1;
    if(i <= count){
        StringBuilder toto = new StringBuilder("L" + i);
        "toto".setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop would not work: The if-statement is executed exactly once, and that's it! And don't call your TextEdits L1, L2, ... The names must start with a small letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem a bit more elegantly using a `HashMap`:

```
EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
⋮   // Fill in the other 8 lines
EditText et10 = findViewById(R.id.et10);

HashMap<Integer, EditText> et = new HashMap<>();
et.put(1, et1);
⋮   // Fill in the other 8 lines
et.put(10, et10);

for (int i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
  et.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: I guess, this is the nearest and neat method. Once the initial definitions are done, it is easy for rest of manipulations. Accepted this as Answer

Answer (score 0):

In this given scenario you can implement the `when` statement (switch-case kotlin)
for reference here is the answer
[How to implement switch-case statement in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138172/how-to-implement-switch-case-statement-in-kotlin)

You can set the flag in your XML and set true or false depending on the scenario example code provided below

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/yourTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.l1 || viewModel.l2 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If we use switch case, still we need to fill the commands manually. What I need is for L1 to L4 unhide the EditTexts

Comment: I'm trying. But how to enable for 10 different cases in Java? Can we get something like this - "toto".setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  maybe contents of toto (&toto or something like that). I use java

Comment: No that's not possible you have to write the cases